# How to find the general solution of the difference equation

Tags: numerical-methods, recurrence-relations

[image]

Take this as an example. Wondering if someone can elaborate their ideas. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you familiar with the method of characteristic polynomials?

Comment: Pretty much yeah. Are you suggesting that I can solve them as a characteristic polynomials? Maybe I can rewrite it as $u^2=u+1$?

Comment: Yes, as in the answer by KonKan. Alternately, one can use the generating function. You recurrence is the important *Fibonacci recurrence.*

Comment: How am I supposed to find all initial values $u_0 and u_1$ such that $u_j$ remains bounded by a constant as j approaches infinity?

Comment: We want to force $c_1=0$. Let $u_0=a$ and $u_1=b$.  Then $c_1+c_2=a$ and $c_1x_1+c_2x_2=b$. So we want $ax_2=b$. You know the value of $x_2$.

Comment: Wait.. I know the value of $x_2$ and an equation of a and b. So I can only find the relation between a and b, but I think I am supposed to find the values of a and b?

Comment: I gave the ratio between $a$ and $b$  in an earlier comment. One cannot do  more, since if $(a,b)$ is a good pair  then so is $(ka,kb)$.

Comment: So one can only find the ratio between a and b, but not the exact values?

Comment: Yes,  that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial for the given recurrence is:
$$
x^2-x-1=0
$$
with distinct, real roots $x_{1,2}=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$

The general solution to the given recurrence is:
$$
\psi=c_1x_1^n+c_2x_2^n
$$

Comment: Or $u_n=u_0F_{n-1}+u_1F_n$ with the Fibonacci sequence starting with $F_{-1}=1,F_0=0, F_1=1$.

Comment: How am I supposed to find all initial values $u_0 and u_1$ such that $u_j$ remains bounded by a constant as j approaches infinity?

Comment: Since $|x_1| > 1$ and $|x_2| <1$, to have the solution bounded you muct have $c_1 = 0$.